# Make a call-button

Tags: java, android, android-activity, phone-call

I am trying to add multiple buttons to my app so if you click one you automatically call a certain person, but now I'm stuck on the call-action, how can I make a call when there is being clicked on the button? I have the following code for my activity named telefoonnummers.java:

```
package com.example.rome;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Telefoonnummers extends Activity {

Button mHALbellen;
Button mWITbellen;
Button mWDGbellen;
Button mVlierbellen;
Button mHotelbellen;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_telefoonnummers);
    mHALbellen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mWITbellen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mWDGbellen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    mVlierbellen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    mHotelbellen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_telefoonnummers, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void vanHalbellen(View view){
    if (view == mHALbellen){
        //WHICH CODE SHOULD BE HERE TO MAKE A PHONECALL WHEN THE BUTTON  mHALBELLEN IS PRESSED??
            }
        }
}
```

Would you guys please help???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

And then execute this Intent when the button is clicked:

```
String uri = "tel: phone_number_here";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

You can also use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL`. This shows the dialer with the number already entered, but allows the user to decide wether to actually make the call or not. `ACTION_DIAL` doesn't require the `CALL_PHONE` permission.